# Wordpress - next_post_link/previous_post_link giving text instead of links

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm simply trying to output the links to next or previous page of posts on homepage. Say, I've 5 posts visible on first page, click on next, go to next 5.

This is my code:

```
        // if previous link exists, show link
        if( get_previous_post_link() ) : ?>
            <li class="next">
                <?php previous_post_link( __( 'Newer Posts &rarr;', 'blog' ) ); ?>
            </li> <?php
        endif;

        // if next link exists, show link
        if( get_next_post_link() ) : ?>
            <li class="previous">
                <?php next_post_link( __( '&larr; Older Posts', 'blog' ) ); ?>                 </li> <?php
        endif; 

    ?>
</ul>
```

The output I'm getting is:

[image]

Plain Text, No Links.

I'm confused. Searched for solutions but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions you are using is to navigate between single posts. What you need is

- [`next_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link)
- [`previous_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link)

Comment: Yeah, about to.. SO says i've to wait few minutes.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat there is a waiting period, I think it is fifteen or twenty minutes. If it is within that time, you cannot accept answers. This is how the system works. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?php next_post_link( __( '%link','&larr; Older Posts', 'blog' ) ); ?>
<?php previous_post_link( __('%link','Newer Posts &rarr;', 'blog' ) ); ?>
```

Found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/nextprevious-post-link-alternative-text)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' , in_same_cat, 'excluded_categories '); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', in_same_cat, 'excluded_categories '); ?>
```

Use This It Will Work